# Junit for fibonnacci Series

Tags: java, junit, junit4

How can i write Jnuit test case for Fibonnacci Series, Using parameterized Test?

```
    public static int fibonnacci(int number) {
    if (number == 1 || number == 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    return fibonnacci(number - 1) + fibonnacci(number - 2);
```

Comment: What version of Junit are you using, and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Google: junit tdd fibonacci example => http://www.jroller.com/jeddi/entry/test_driven_development_fibonacci_to

Comment: Good luck with this implementation...it will quickly fail.  You shouldn't use a recursive method for finding Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @Jared Thanks for the info, may I know i shouldn't use recursive method for finding Fibonnacci numbers.

Comment: @user2900314 I am Junit version 4

Answer (score 2):

Try simple test like:

```
public class MyClassTest {
    MyClass clazz;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        clazz = new MyClass();
    }
    @Test
    public void testFibbonacciWithOneAsInput() {//write different test cases and test for edge cases, normal cases something like below.
         Assert.assertEquals(clazz.fibonnacci(1), 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample From the official documentaion for [Parameterized-tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests)

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
                 { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 },{ 6, 8 }  
           });
    }

    private int fInput;
    private int fExpected;

    public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
        fInput= input;
        fExpected= expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.compute(fInput));
    }
}
```